# Cross Site Scripting issue with window.location.search

Tags: javascript, xss

I have been going through so many forums & wikipedia's since few days for trying to understand about XSS attacks alomost I have spent 2-3 days but still not get better idea as suggesting multiple solutions by experts & I want know how the hackers can inject malicious code on victims browser ? and my application have been use to run on some App Scanner standard testing tool so its caught so many XSS issues. I want put here one of XSS issue of my application so can please some one help me out to understand the what exactly I have to do for this issue. Still I have been trying a lot to get better understand about XSS issues. This is my code snippet

```js
function getParameter(param) {
        var val = "";
        var qs = window.location.search;
        var start = qs.indexOf(param);
        if (start != -1) {
                start += param.length + 1;
                var end = qs.indexOf("&", start);
                if (end == -1) {
                        end = qs.length
                }
                val = qs.substring(start,end);
        }
        return val;
}

var formName = getParameter("formName");
var myValue = '<a href="javascript:parent.opener.assignDateIps( new Date(\''+year+'\',\''+month+'\',\''+thisDay+'\'), \''+contextstr+'\', \''+formName+'\' );window.close()" class="modulelink">'+thisDay+'</a></td>';
document.getElementById('calendarA').innerHTML = myValue;
```

And these statements are

```
var qs = window.location.search;
val = qs.substring(start,end);
var formName = getParameter("formName");
var myValue = '<a href="javascript:parent.opener.assignDateIps( new Date(\''+year+'\',\''+month+'\',\''+thisDay+'\'), \''+contextstr+'\', \''+formName+'\' );window.close()" class="modulelink">'+thisDay+'</a></td>';
document.getElementById('calendarA').innerHTML = myValue;
```

cought by App scanner testing tool as possible code for XSS(Cross Site Scripting) issues but I am not sure how it is cause to XSS & how I can fix this issue now. Can anybody please provide insights on how this vulnerability can be fixed?

Comment: How do you use `formName` variable?

Comment: Hi Qwertiy, I am new to this application just joined few days back & directly working on XSS issues. As a developer I can say its is queryString param name & pass this param to getParameter() function & try to fetch the value of that param using window.location.search.

Comment: How do you use the value afrer fetching it?

Comment: I think you could add your snippet on how you use the variable `formName` in your program..

Comment: Sure Qwerity, Rajasuba

Comment: This "formName" value have been using in this var myValue = '<a href="javascript:parent.opener.assignDateIps( new Date(\''+year+'\',\''+month+'\',\''+thisDay+'\'), \''+contextstr+'\', \''+formName+'\' );window.close()" class="modulelink">'+thisDay+'</a></td>';

Comment: And finally injecting on webpage document.getElementById('calendarA').innerHTML = myValue;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> var myValue = '<a href="javascript:parent.opener.assignDateIps( new Date(\''+year+'\',\''+month+'\',\''+thisDay+'\'), \''+contextstr+'\', \''+formName+'\' );window.close()" class="modulelink">'+thisDay+'</a></td>';
> ```

This line doesn't have any escaping, it expects `'(... \''+formName+'\' );...'` to be a string. But it can become some other thing:

```
formName = "'); alert('I\'m free to do anything here'); (''+"
```

> ```
> document.getElementById('calendarA').innerHTML = myValue;
> ```

Let's place such fragment into `myValue`:

```
... <img src=void onerror="alert('hacked')" /> ...
```

You can check it works:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.querySelector('output').innerHTML = document.querySelector('textarea').value;
})
```

```html
<textarea>... <img src=void onerror="alert('hacked')" /> ...</textarea>
<button>Go</button>
<output></output>
```

You should never trust any data passed by url string. Any site can place any link to you site. Some user clicks it, goes to your site, parameters are executed in context of your site, and attacker can do anything he wants to.

Comment: Thank you so much Qwertiy for given brife explanation. As you mentioned this statement `var myValue = '<a href="javascript:parent.opener.assignDateIps( new Date(\''+year+'\',\''+month+'\',\''+thisDay+'\'), \''+contextstr+'\', \''+formName+'\' );window.close()" class="modulelink">'+thisDay+'</a></td>';` doesn't have any escaping it means what I can do for this I have already imported ESAPI library in my application but I am not sure how I can use it. Any sample code in this how I can do escaping to this code.

Comment: Please help me Qwertiy for one instance then I will anylise accordingly to my next issues.

Comment: @Venki, there is not enought content to help.

Comment: I can understand Qwerty but thing is I am new to this so its taking time even I am putting 100% efforts. Anyhow thanks for yours help. And I have accepted yours answer.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in the code you've shown us is vulnerable.

You are reading user input, so there is the potential to introduce a vulnerability there. That is *probably* what the tool you are using is detecting.

If your code *is* vulnerable, then it will be because of whatever you do with the value of `formName` next (in the code you haven't shown us).

Comment: Hi Quentin, your's guess is right. This "formName"  value been using in this var myValue = '<a href="javascript:parent.opener.assignDateIps( new Date(\''+year+'\',\''+month+'\',\''+thisDay+'\'), \''+contextstr+'\', \''+formName+'\' );window.close()" class="modulelink">'+thisDay+'</a></td>';

Comment: Any help on this please ? I have modified my question as much as clear now

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible DOM based XSS issue.

If you are using the value of `formName` like `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=formName` or somehow your DOM elements are being created/modified using the `formName` you are vulnerable, 
as i can create a custom url like `http://urwebsite.html?formName=<script>document.cookie_will_be_transfered_to_my_server_here</script>` and ask a logged in person to click it(simple social engineering) .Now i have that person's session id, using which i can do what ever i want.

As a resolution, all the input data from the user has to be html encoded.

Comment: Hi Vinod, looks you are answered my question but here I have one cofusion i.e what is the final url behalf of `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML` on webpage is  ?

Comment: Hi Vinod, I am putting my final understanding so far as I mentioned in my code snippet `myValue` variable having `<a>` tag with some url
 & that url having `formName` as part of queryparam in that url so now as you created a custom url like `http://urwebsite.html?formName=<script>document.cookie_will_be_transfered_to_my_server_here</script>` 
 is going to replace with `formName` which was a part of actual url then if user try to clicks on this element `document.getElementById('calendarA').innerHTML` on webpage then user redirects to attacker intension page ?

Comment: Not the `<script>`, but `<img src=//never.here/none onerror=... />`. script is not executed when passed into `innerHTML`.

Comment: Hi Qwerity, I am not getting. Its really helpful we have complete end to end example. Still I am going through so many forums but not getting clear picture :(

Comment: @Vinod : If it is possible please  try to make my code snippet as anti XSS code then I hope its makes everyone as better understanding. Ty in advance.